# Can an IIFE be added to a browserify bundle?

Tags: gulp, browserify

I am trying to add the Zurb Foundation 5 library into my build process by adding it to my browserify task. I *currently have things working by having 2 script tags*:

```
<script src="all_foundation_files.min.js</script>
<script src="rest_of_my_app_browserify_bundle.js</script>
```

*But I'd **really** like to do away with that second, unnecessary HTTP request*.

If it isn't already clear, `all_foundation_files.min.js` is an IIFE which basically just adds properties to the the `document` element.

I've tried using `browserify-shim` but I don't believe that is what I want to use (or I'm using it wrong) as I don't really need to `require()` this package in other modules **and** `all_foundation_files` could be a bunch of concatenated IIFE and I don't want to have each one configured.

All I want is to basically ***have these functions invoked when the browserify `bundle.js` is requested*** in the `index.html`. Is this possible or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Add it as an entry file when browserifying.